# Do animals have social status as humans in our society?

Tags: human-biology, behaviour

As our society and it's functioning is closely related to the ones of animals, one question arises: Do animals in nature have social status as humans? People often display it publicly, by buying nice cars, searching for women and partners and so on, accumulating wealth and so on. Does similar things happens in nature? How our behavior is similar to animals?

Comment: Are you asking if animals try to show off social status?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: Animals certainly have social status as evidenced in the idea of 'pecking order' or dominance behaviors in canine packs. 

I think the more interesting question (perhaps what you are looking for) is whether non-human animals 'dress up' their social order either to deceive others about their standing or reinforce their position in society. 

If this is the question, then natural displays don't really count. More specifically, is there evidence of animals 'affecting' a position in 'pecking order' that is not theirs otherwise? Or perhaps ask, ' why do men buy BMWs?'